# iText: Insert pdf bytes into an opened document

Tags: itext

Currently, our team is using Image.getInstance(bytes[]) to get an image object from png bytes. But later we will use a pdf file instead of png. So my question is that given pdf bytes, is there any way to convert it into png bytes or insert into opened document?

Something like this:
void insertIntoDocument(byte[] pdfBytes, Document document){}

Comment: Which version of iText are you using- 5? It should be possible to construct a new `PdfReader` object and merge it with the existing document like so: https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly.